# Which matrices can be square roots of Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

I have a square matrix $Q$. (I can additionally assume that it is invertible
${\rm det}\,Q \ne 0$,
but I don't see how this helps.) I define yet another square matrix
$Q_2 = Q^2$.
This new matrix is happen to be Hermitian
$Q_2^\dagger = Q_2$.
Here is the question: how can I describe the set of such $Q$'s whose squares are Hermitian?

Obviously, if
$Q$
is Hermitian,
$Q^2$
is also Hermitian. Additionally, if
$Q$
is anti-Hermitian (that is,
$Q^\dagger = - Q$),
$Q^2$
is Hermitian.
The most broad set of matrices I am able to come up with is this:
$Q = U^\dagger D U$,
where $U$ is unitary, while
$$D = {\rm diag}\, (d_1,..., d_n),$$
where any
$d_\alpha$ ($\alpha = 1,..., n$)
is either purely real, or purely imaginary. Does this exhaust all possible $Q$'s with the desired property, or other possibilities are possible?

**In response to comments/replies, I want to make the following modification to the original problem.**

Matrix
$Q_2$
is Hermitian. I want to describe its square roots (that is, all matrices $Q$, such that
$Q^2 = Q_2$).

My improved guess is the following. If
$$Q_2 = U^\dagger D_2 U,$$
where $U$ is unitary, and
$D_2 = {\rm diag}\,(d^{(2)}_1,..., d^{(2)}_n)$
is diagonal, then
$$Q = U^\dagger X^{-1} D X U,$$
where
$$D = {\rm diag}\,(\pm \sqrt{d^{(2)}_1}, ..., \pm \sqrt{d^{(2)}_n})$$
while $X$ is an invertible matrix that commutes with
$D_2$:
$XD_2 = D_2 X$.
Does this description exhaust all possible $Q$'s?

Comment: These are called the square roots of $Q_2$. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3485136/find-a-square-root-of-a-hermitian-matrix), how to compute the square roots. There are also non-Hermitian square roots in general - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580407/is-the-square-root-of-a-positive-semi-definite-hermitian-matrix-also-hermitian).

Comment: For a given Hermitian matrix $Q_2$ **with distinct eigenvalues**, if $Q^2 = Q_2$ then $Q$ must satisfy $QQ^\dagger = Q^\dagger Q$. If $Q_2$ has positive eigenvalues, this means that $Q$ is Hermitian. If $Q_2$ has negative eigenvalues, this means that $Q$ is skew-Hermitian.